# How to get around missing method ListView.performItemLongClick?

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a listview and need to simulate a long click on one of the list items, but no performItemLongClick method exists. 
Since View has both performClick and performLongClick defined, and since ListView already has performItemClick, it seems like it should also have performItemLongClick. 
Could they just have forgotten to implement or expose it?

Anyway, my question is, how to best get around this?
I tried (ab)using performItemClick and using the id parameter to tell whether it was a click or a longclick, but the click event is apparently fired on the up action, so now I get a longclick immediately followed by a regular click.

I know that I could set a flag on the long click and ignore the following click, but that is not the kind of solution I am looking for. I figure someone here has a better way.

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and i've not found any workaround to perform a "long click" on a item contained in an ArrayAdapter.

So, i've declared an issue on android isue tracker : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 24/01/2014, two and a half years after the original question, this is still not supported in the API (level 19/Android 4.4).

As nobody has provided any alternative, that is going to have to be answer to the question.

Comment: Can't you just call the method that would be executed if it was long-pressed?

Comment: Not for all use cases, otherwise this type of method wouldn't have any justification for existing.

Answer (score 2):

It's sad that after more than 3 years there is still no performItemLongClick() method.

I know it is a workaround but you may try this - worked for me:

```
AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener = adapterView.getOnItemLongClickListener();
if (listener != null) {
    listener.onItemLongClick(adapterView, view, position, id);
}
```

The last three arguments are the same our missing performItemLongClick(...) method would have.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, and I think the best solution is just to use Robotium for testing in Android. It cleaned up so many lines of code I had into simple methods. For making a long item click it is as simple as `solo.clickLongInList(position)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on sending touch events. So it not only invokes long click listener handler, but actually performs long click on item:

```
fun ListView.performItemLongClick(position: Int) {
    val itemView = this.adapter.getView(position, null, this)
    val coords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    itemView.getLocationOnScreen(coords)

    this.performTouch(
        x = coords[0].toFloat() + 1f,
        y = coords[1].toFloat() + 1f,
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
    )

    Shadows.shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idleFor(
        ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout().toLong(),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    )
}


fun View.performTouch(x: Float, y: Float, action: Int) {
    val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - 100
    val eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

    this.dispatchTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            action,
            x,
            y,
            0
        )
    )
}
```

This function optimized for robolectric usage, so long click would be performed before exiting this function. For use in production comment this lines: `Shadows.shadowOf...`
Usage:

```
val listView = findViewById(...)
listView.performItemLongClick(3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {  

@Override 

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {  

    return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);  

}
```

});

Comment: Thank you, but I know how to listen for a longClick event, what I need to know is how to trigger it from code. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: You can trigger a click from code using listview.performItemClick, I just want to trigger a long click. If you're unsure of what I mean by "from code", it is simply triggering the click event from within your program as opposed to physically triggering the click with your finger on the display.

Answer (score -2):

or try contextmenu,first register the listview by 
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

```
@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info; 
    try { 
         info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo; 
    } catch (ClassCastException e) { 
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e); 
        return; 
    } 
    long l = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position); 
} `
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?